# Why am I unable to change the password on my Mac?

Tags: macos, security, password, settings

I recently purchased my Macbook Air from school and they said that they have disconnected it from their server. But when I try to change the password for the admin account it shows me the following message:

> The server is not available. Change your password when the server becomes available.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Password for what? User, Admin, some website??

Comment: Not sure if https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860 applies. Could you edit your post to show what specific scenario you are using to change a password?

Comment: Trying to change the password for the admin account. @SolarMike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my Mac and used the [following script](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/migrating-ad-mobile-accounts-to-local-user-accounts/) to convert my AD-user account to a local one which I have total control over the password.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was finally able to change my password.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around into this issue and there must have been an error when the computer was disconnected from the AD (Active Directory) and the domain controller. One thing I read is that reconnecting it back to the AD/server and disconnecting it again will allow you to change your password. That method was discovered from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/754071). Another thing could be an error with the school's domain controller. The systems administrator setting a preferred domain controller can fix this issue as pointed out [here](https://serverfault.com/a/376686).